# Error: Expected spy create to have been called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit test cases in angular 7 for a [Component with async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service) and getting this error:

> Error: Expected spy create to have been called once. It was called 0
> times.

Here is my Component:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    
   submitRegistrationForm() {
        if (this.profileForm.invalid) {
          this.validateAllFields(this.profileForm);
        } else {
          // send a http request to save this data
          this.guestUserService.create(this.profileForm.value).subscribe(
            result => {
              if (result) {
                console.log('result', result);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              }
            },
            error => {
              console.log('error', error);
            });
        }
  }
```

Unit test case:

```
  describe('RegistrationComponent', () => {
      let component: RegistrationComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<RegistrationComponent>;
      let myService;
      let mySpy;
    
      beforeEach(async(() => {
    
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [RegistrationComponent],
          imports: [ ],
          providers: [
            { provide: GuestUserService, useValue: new MyServiceStub() }]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      }));
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegistrationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

 it('should submit Registration Form', async(inject([Router], (router) => {
    myService = TestBed.get(GuestUserService);
    mySpy = spyOn(myService, 'create');
    spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    spyOn(component, 'submitRegistrationForm');


component.profileForm.controls['firstName'].setValue('Arjun');
    component.profileForm.controls['lastName'].setValue('Singh');
    component.profileForm.controls['password'].setValue('12345678');
    component.profileForm.controls['confirmPassword'].setValue('12345678');
    component.submitRegistrationForm();

    expect(component.profileForm.invalid).toBe(false);

    expect(component.submitRegistrationForm).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(myService).toBeDefined();
    expect(mySpy).toBeDefined();
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Getting error is this
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
  ));
```

I tried to move the spy deceleration in beforeEach but still its giving the same error.

how to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change your line showing error like this and try - `expect(myService .create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Comment: You need to either `detectChanges` or call `done` (after injecting it) after calling the method under test and before your expects.

Comment: Hello @user2216584, I have tried this expect(myService .create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Hi @TheHeadRush, fixture.detectChanges(); didn't worked as well.

Comment: @ArjunSingh It appears that your component's else condition is not being executed. Put `console.log` in `if` and `else` condition and see what gets logs. By seeing your test case it appears that your component's `this.profileForm` is invalid and because of that your `submitRegistrationForm` method's else condition is not being executed. Are you sure that else condition of `submitRegistrationForm` is called? put logs and check.

Comment: @user2216584, No profileForm values are set and getting this.profileForm.invalid as false i.e else condition needs to be executed. Updated the test case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Expected spy create to have been called is not an Error but a failed test.

This is happening because you haven't use callThrough(); on your spyOn either.

```
 it('should submit Registration Form', async(inject([Router], (router) => {

    myService = TestBed.get(GuestUserService);
    mySpy = spyOn(myService, 'create').and.callThrough(); //callThrough()

    spyOn(router, 'navigate');

    spyOn(component, 'submitRegistrationForm').and.callThrough(); //callThrough()


    component.submitRegistrationForm();

    expect(component.profileForm.invalid).toBe(false);

    expect(component.submitRegistrationForm).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(myService).toBeDefined();
    expect(mySpy).toBeDefined();
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); 
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
  ));
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works wonder with form controls.

Answer (score 9):

The `spyOn` will help you to setup how the function should react when it's being called upon in your tests. Basically it's Jasmines way of creating mocks.

In your case you have defined what the test should do when the service function is being called, which is `callThrough`. The problem is that you also need to act on the service function (or the scope function which calls your service method) in order to trigger the `spyOn` which will `callThrough`.

```
it('load snapshot',function(){

  //setup
  spyOn(MyService, 'loadSomething').and.callThrough(); //statement 2

  //act

  //either call the scope function which uses the service 
  //$scope.yourServiceCallFunction();

  //or call the service function directly
  MyService.loadSomething(1); //this will callThrough

});
```

Here's an simple test where we will mock the response of the `spyOn` to a string

```
it('test loadSomething',function(){

  //setup
  spyOn(MyService, 'loadSomething').and.returnValue('Mocked');

  //act
  var val = MyService.loadSomething(1);

  //check
  expect(val).toEqual('Mocked');
});
```